# crontab environment

Tags: bash, solaris, cron, bashrc

I have written various scripts to launch Java server applications, which are typically run for 24 hours before being shut down (by invoking the same script with a different parameter).

The script relies on environment variables defined in a file: `~/<user>.env`, which I source from `.bashrc`.

This works fine when invoking the script from the command line but if I want to add the script as a crontab entry I run into the problem where `.bashrc` isn't read.

My question: What is the best practice approach for solving this problem?  I realise I could define a crontab entry such as:

```
* * * * 1-5 /usr/bin/bash -c '. /home/myuser/myuser.env && /home/myuser/scripts/myscript.sh'
```

... but this seems plain ugly.  Alternatively I could source `myuser.env` at the beginning of every script, but this would become a nightmare to maintain.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Those are the two options I would suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually discovered a fairly elegant solution by adding the '-l' (--login) flag to my bash command, which causes it to source all login files, including .bashrc.  Hence my crontab command is simply:

```
* * * * 1-5 /usr/bin/bash -lc '/mnt/group/core/deploy/scripts/test.sh' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: In this case (and really any solution to this issue), make sure you're not putting interactive-only things in your profile or bashrc without at least testing for the presence of a tty.

Answer (score 11):

I usually address this with a short cron wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc
[ -r $HOME/.profile ] && . $HOME/.profile
exec "$@"
```

Then just prefix the command in crontab with your wrapper:

```
* * * * 1-5 ~/scripts/cron-wrapper ~/scripts/myscript.sh
* * * * 1-5 ~/scripts/cron-wrapper ~/scripts/myotherscript.sh
```

[Some versions of cron](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5&arch=i386&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current) allow you to set variables directly in crontab.  Unfortunately, I don't get to use those at work.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (although not necessarily better) option would be to add these into root's crontab, and have the entry use su with a dash to become the user in question.  The environment variables would then be pulled in automatically via the user's default shell environment in ~/.bashrc, or the like.  eg:

`* * * * 1-5 su - scriptuser '/home/myuser/scripts/myscript.sh'`  This would run the job as scriptuser, with all the environment variables of a proper login.  The downside is that scriptuser himself couldn't set this job up -- it would require root privileges to do that.

Answer (score 1):

cron-wrapper solution worked for me with one modification, I needed to replace the $HOME with the absolute path to the user home folder, in this case it was:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -r /root/.bashrc ] && . /root/.bashrc
[ -r /root/.profile ] && . /root/.profile
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can think of would be based on:

```
bash -i --rcfile 'init' -c 'script'
```

which is probably less attractive.

Comment: I actually tried this and it doesn't work.  According to the GNU bash manual, --rcfile "Execute commands from filename (instead of ~/.bashrc) in an interactive shell.", and as I'm not running an interactive shell I presume this is why it's failing.

Comment: @Adamski: The `-i` makes the shell think it's interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of cron allow you to set arbitrary environment variables before running jobs.  So you could add this to your crontab:

CRON=1

Then in your .bash_login do something like this:

[ -n "$CRON" ] && . .bashrc